# Passing elements to another page from an appended list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tizen-web-app

I have an appended list in my javascript file of the following format.

```
  $("#ultag").append($("<li onclick=\"next(this.id);\" id=\"litag\"><div id=\"litagdiv\"><div id=\"imgdiv\"><img id=\"listimg\" alt=\"picture\" src="+file_image+"></div><img id=\"help_picture\"  src=\"images/call_icon_list_black.png\"><div id=\"datadiv\"><div id=\"distance\">"+final_distance+"  mts"+"</div><div id=\"gulpname\">"+file_name+"</div><br><div id=\"gulpaddress\">"+file_address+"</div><div id=\"time\">Open till  "+""+file_time+"</div></div></div></li>"));
```

I want to pass the file_address and file_name and image to another html page.

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: I tried.But it wasn't working.I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or not.The result will be empty when i logged it

Comment: Are you working on mobile apps?

Comment: Ya ,I'm working on Tizen app

Comment: @Arjunpnair i dnt know about Tizen app but can you tell me it will use cordova local storage is not good option for mobile

Comment: I don't thin it will be using cordova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local storage to store values :

```
var gulpaddress = $('#gulpaddress').text();
localStorage.setItem("file_address", gulpaddress );
```

And get the item saved :

```
localStorage.getItem("file_address");
```

**Updated**

If you have multiple elements that need share the same name for example an id, use class instead, otherwise the first matched element only returned. See below example :

Change this :

```
<li onclick=\"next(this.id);\" id=\"litag\">..
<div id=\"gulpaddress\">..
```

Into this(*remove onclick inline js and id attribute*) :

```
<li class=\"litag\">..
<div class=\"gulpaddress\">..
```

Then your js :

```
// here we register handler to all matched class
$('#ultag').on('click','.litag', function () {
    // and find only descendants element of current click 
    var gulpaddress = $(this).find('.gulpaddress').text();
    ..... 
    localStorage.setItem("file_address", gulpaddress );
    .......
    .......
});
```

Comment: The problem I had earlier was, whenever I click a list item only the address of the first item is getting passed.Even if I click on the last item,the address of the first element is getting passed.

Comment: Did you register the click handler into this ids for li element `#litag` ? If yes, change into class definition instead, as id must be unique no matter what.

Comment: I've changed the li tags definition into class.Is that what you meant?

Comment: I've understand that .But the click handler is not working now.I've added the location href for the page to navigate on your given function.But it is not navigating.

Comment: put alert inside click handler function and see if that getting called or not

Comment: $('#ultag').on('click','.litag', function () {
    // and find only descendants element of current click
 alert("hfjh");
    var gulpaddress = $(this).find('.gulpaddress').text();
    var hellas=localStorage.setItem("file_address", gulpaddress );
    alert(hellas);
    window.location.href = "phssdetails.html";
});

Comment: Nothing.No alert on click

Comment: Sorry about that.I was so wrapped up in this,I haven't noticed that.Thank you sir.It's working perfect now

Comment: Will it be possible to localstorage an image?

Comment: Better store its source `eg : src`

Comment: var gulpimage = $(this).find('.listimg').src();

Comment: But when i use that,the click handler gets stopped working

Comment: Because it not valid jquery code. Use this instead `var gulpimage = $(this).find('.listimg').attr('src');`

Comment: ya>forgot about that.Ty mate